# How to run multiple dotnet command within one build step in Cloud Build?

Tags: .net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to build my .net core project by using Cloud Build. There are some testing projects exist in the solution, and I want to run tests within the build step. In the cloudbuild.yaml file I tried to do this but seems like Cloud Build doesn't like it:

```
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/dotnet"
  entrypoint: "dotnet"
  args:
    - |
        test --no-build -c ${_BUILD_CONFIG} $REPO_NAME.Tests
        test --no-build -c ${_BUILD_CONFIG} $REPO_NAME.Common.Tests
```

So I'm wondering how to combine multiple multiple dotnet commands within one build step?

Comment: I just find out I can run "dotnet test ." command to run all test projects under current project directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/dotnet"
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
        dotnet test --no-build -c ${_BUILD_CONFIG} $REPO_NAME.Tests
        dotnet test --no-build -c ${_BUILD_CONFIG} $REPO_NAME.Common.Tests
```

try this